# How to use Amazon ACM cert with Cloudfront?

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3, https, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront

I created an ssl certificate using ACM and it seems to be issues just fine:
[image]

**I then created a cloudfront distribution, but I can't seem to select the certificate which I just created:**

[image]

**Does anybody know why the certificate can't be found by the cloudfront distribution?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note to self; reading helps :-)

[image]

Comment: It does, indeed.  CloudFront is of course globally distributed, but its provisioning HQ is in us-east-1, so that's the region where the certificates need to be provisioned in order for CloudFront to see them.  You also may have missed the message displayed in the ACM console in all other regions that certificates in those regions can only be used with Elastic and Application Load Balancers.

Comment: I had the same issue and even after creating a certificate in us-east-1 I was still having the issue of the Custom SSL Certificate option being unavailable. Turned out waiting a few minutes for the certificate to propagate through AWS' systems did the trick.